git can't delete remote branch because of distant ref/head
I work on several computers and use a bare repository on HDD to synchronize them. It works fine but I have a problem with a specific remote branch :

I define a temporary branch newDev to differentiate from dev.

I pushed it and work with both for a while but now they are merged with master and I want to delete them everywhere ... here began my problem

dev and newDev are both deldeted from the locals : git branch -d dev ... : ok

origine/dev is deleted : git push origin :dev : ok

but it doesn't work with origin/newDev


Here are the different commands and results (my git is configured in french ;-)):
git push origin :newDev :
remote: error: Par défaut, supprimer la branche actuelle est refusé parce que le
remote: prochain 'git clone' n'extraira aucun fichier et causer de la confusion.
remote: 
remote: Vous pouvez régler « receive.denyDeleteCurrent » à 'warn' ou 'ignore'
remote: dans le dépôt distant pour permettre la suppression la branche actuelle
remote: avec ou sans message d'avertissement.
remote: 
remote: Pour éliminer ce message, réglez-le à 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/newDev
To /media/fafi_dev/ALSEAMAR-Acoustics-Disk3/gitRepositories/OCIA_API.git/
 ! [remote rejected] newDev (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: impossible de pousser des références vers '/media/fafi_dev/ALSEAMAR-Acoustics-Disk3/gitRepositories/OCIA_API.git/'


`git remote show origin' :
* distant origin
  URL de rapatriement : /media/fafi_dev/ALSEAMAR-Acoustics-Disk3/gitRepositories/OCIA_API.git/
  URL push : /media/fafi_dev/ALSEAMAR-Acoustics-Disk3/gitRepositories/OCIA_API.git/
  Branche HEAD : newDev
  Branches distantes :
    dev_Fab suivi
    master  suivi
    newDev  suivi
  Branches locales configurées pour 'git pull' :
    dev_Fab fusionne avec la distante dev_Fab
    master  fusionne avec la distante master
  Références locales configurées pour 'git push' :
    dev_Fab pousse vers dev_Fab (à jour)
    master  pousse vers master  (à jour)

git branch -r :
  origin/HEAD -> origin/newDev
  origin/dev_Fab
  origin/master
  origin/newDev

git remote set-head -d origin : nothing happend (no error, no info), the result of git remote show origin' is the same as before **but** git branch -r` gives :
  origin/dev_Fab
  origin/master
  origin/newDev

and git push origin :newDev produce the same error.
I tried also git remote set-head -a origin which answer : origin/HEAD set to newDev
Does anybody have some solution and explanations ?
Thanks a lot !

Thanks to this response I understand that git remote set-head do the change on the local. Unlike this post I resolved the problem just by editing HEAD file in the remote bare repo and changing the line ref: refs/heads/newDev whith ref: refs/heads/master.
Then in the local, git remote update origine : the change was effective and the command git push origin :newDev worked.
May this post help someone ??

Your remote has origin/newDev checked out. So you will need to do something like
git checkout master

on your remote in order not to have HEAD pointing to it and try again. Alternatively, you can try
git config receive.denyDeleteCurrent false

again, on your remote. Make sure that you do not execute these on your local, but either ssh your remote or access it by other means (remote desktop or something of the like)
